# Magento 2 sender emails incorrectly to customers

Tags: adobe, magento2

There are 2 stores and you are only sending the email from one store instead of each store sending the correct sender.

I checked in the template of one of the emails and the subject is configured correctly.
`<!--@subject {{trans "Your %store_name order has been canceled" store_name=$store.frontend_name}} @-->`

Even using $store.frontend_name it does't work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To configure the email of the sender is not in html template.

This configuration is in the Magento Admin Panel in **stores > Configuration > Store Email Addresses**, then you must verify if your website was configured using **General Contact** or **Sales representative**, in those fields there are 2 options, **sender name** and **sender email**, fill them correctly.

Important! Before fill the fields you must verify **which store you selected** in **scope option**, you said that need use for 2 stores, ok so you must fill options in order to achieve each store configurations you want.

[image]